# Excel: Compare two columns and print only differences in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two software management solutions that are both for the most part installed on my target computers.  However, there are some exceptions, so I want to have a list of the computer names that are covered by one solution but not the other.

Just about everything I can find simply shows a running list of each value and then a "True" or "False"

I want simply a list of each result.

Source data is like this:

Management Solution 1 - Two columns, one for Device Name and one for the Domain it is part of.

**Management Solution 1**

| Device Name | Domain |
| --- | --- |
| Win-10-1 | Alpha |
| Win-10-2 | Alpha |
| Win-7-1 | Beta |

**Management Solution 2**

| Device Name | Domain |
| --- | --- |
| Win-10-1 | Alpha |
| Win-10-2 | Alpha |
| Win-7-2 | Beta |

So we can see that Win-7-2 in Domain Beta exists in the device list for Management Solution 2, but not on the list for Management Solution 1.

We can see that Win-7-1 exists on the list for Management Solution 1 but not the list for Management Solution 2

The list of differences is actually going to be on a different sheet than the raw data.

But this list should be a simple result:

List of Domain names and Devices that exist in Management Solution 1 but not in Management Solution 2, and then Vice Versa.

**Only in Solution 1**

| Device Name | Domain |
| --- | --- |
| Win-7-1 | Beta |

**Only in Solution 2**

| Device Name | Domain |
| --- | --- |
| Win-7-2 | Beta |

Win-10-1 and Win10-2 are common to both, so I don't want to list them anywhere

I'm dealing with a list of around 850 computers with a difference of course 30 computers.  There may be handful managed by Solution 1, and then a longer list Managed by Solution 2.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: SUMPRODUCT is also a way to count the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an INDEX array formula to return all values of [your criteria]. In this example, my criteria will be looking for a count value 0 (zero), which represents a match to the other data source.

First, add another column to each source data, where you count the number of matches from Source 1 to Source 2 and vice versa.

Cell C3 formula (count nbr of instances in MS2):

```
    =COUNTIFS(E:E,A3,F:F,B3)
```

Cell G3 formula (count nbr of instances in MS1):

```
    =COUNTIFS(A:A,E3,B:B,F3)
```

Drag down your formulas.

Next you can create your list of the missing (zero) values.

Cell I3 formula (array formula, so **press CTRL-ALT-ENTER to get curly brackets**):

```
    {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$6,SMALL(IF(0=$C$3:$C$6,ROW($A$3:$A$6)-ROW($A$3)+1),ROW(1:1))),"")}
```

Drag it down further than you need. It's wrapped with an error handler to display a blank when no more are found.

Cell J3 formula:

```
    =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I3,A:B,2,FALSE),"")
```

Drag it down as far as desired.

Use similar formulas in columns L and M, **but change the reference data accordingly**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Office 365, you can use `XMATCH` and `FILTER`

I create **Tables** for the solution tables and named them `Soln1` and `Soln2`

***Then***
*(entered in the cell just below device name)*
*(results will SPILL to the other cells as needed)*

```
only in Solution 1:  =FILTER(Soln1,ISNA(XMATCH(Soln1[Device Name],Soln2[Device Name])))

only in Solution 2: =FILTER(Soln2, ISNA(XMATCH(Soln2[Device Name],Soln1[Device Name])))
```

`ISNA(XMATCH(...` will return `TRUE` if any entry in the first argument is not present in the second argument; so it can be used as criteria for the `FILTER` function.

[image]